# Missing XCB header in Debian Squeeze/Wheezy

Tags: c, debian, header-files, xcb

The [docs](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/xinput_8h-source.html) talk about a file called `input.h` that doesn't seem to appear in any of the packages, at least according to:

```
apt-file search /usr/include/xcb/xinput.h
```

I need that because I was trying to use the function [`xcb_input_open_device`](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/group__XCB__Input__API.html#gd627b945aee22b9a4977855083e43fa3).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that XInput Extension is disabled by default because it's not yet stable enough; hence not packaged in Debian.

In the `configure` script:

```
--enable-xinput         Build XCB XInput Extension (default: "no")
```